# How do I render a String containing HTML code that a bean returns?

Tags: html, jsp, jsf, web, ejb

I have got a bean that have a method that checks if a user is logged in and returns a String containing HTML code. Is there any way that I can render this String on the webpage after it has been returned?

Answer (score 2):

Of course. In your managed bean:

```
public String checkLogin() {
    return "<h2><b>User was not logged in.</b></h2>";
}
```

And in your xhtml file:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{bean.checkLogin()}" />
```